# umbraco website deploy Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, umbraco, publish, webdeploy

Hi everybody i am stuck at this point hope someone got the answer

Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Umbraco.Web.Runtime.WebRuntime.Boot(IRegister register) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\Runtime\WebRuntime.cs:55

[HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +517
System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +185
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +714

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3650.0

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to give full control permission on the 'httpdocs' folder on the host server

Comment: For better safety, you should give access to the IIS AppPool\<myappoolname> user on rather than use the everyone account